# Repeatedly copying the contents of one file to another

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the contents of one file, and duplicate it several times into another file.  I tried this:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt 5; $i++) { Get-Content source } | Out-File destination
```

But I get the error: "An empty pipe element is not allowed".  Putting parentheses around the for loop like this:

```
(for ($i=0; $i -lt 5; $i++) { Get-Content source }) | Out-File destination
```

results in "Missing closing ')' in expression".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 (get-content source) * 5 | out-file destination
```

Comment: Nice (+1). Still, it also takes 5 times (in this example) more memory than other solutions. For large files or numbers this can be an issue.

Comment: I know, and considered that but it didn't seem likely that someone would want to repeatedly duplicate the contents of a really large file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
1..5 | %{Get-Content source | Out-File destination -append}
```

Or more efficient:

```
$content = Get-Content source; 1..5 | %{Out-File -FilePath destination -InputObject $content -append}
```

EDIT: Forgot the -append

Comment: Almost, but you'll need the `-Append` flag to Out-File, and I'd add a `-ReadCount 0` to the `Get-Content` to speed things up:
`1..5 | Foreach-Object { Get-Content source -ReadCount 0 | Out-File destination -Append }`

Comment: No, I mean I had edited my answer to include the append before your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke the `for` loop as a script block, i.e. something that produces pipeline output (the `for` block itself does not):

```
.{
    for ($i=0; $i -lt 5; $i++) {
        Get-Content source
    }
} |
Out-File destination
```

(you can make it one-liner again, indeed)

P.S. Your second try is almost correct. This works:

```
$(for ($i=0; $i -lt 5; $i++) { Get-Content source }) | Out-File destination
```